# How to create a composite function from a variable number of components?

Tags: function-construction

Background of the problem: A patient takes a drug every $X$ hours with a half-life of $Y$ hours. How much of the drug will be (exactly) in his system after $h$ hours? For $X=24$, and $Y=24$ I made the following function showing the concentration of the drug for the first 96 hours.

```
 Clear[m]
 m[h_] := Exp[-(h/48)] /; h < 24
 m[h_] := Exp[-(h/48)] + Exp[-((h - 24)/48)] /; ( h >= 24 && h < 48)
 m[h_] := Exp[-(h/48)] + Exp[-((h - 24)/48)] + 
     Exp[-((h - 48)/48)] /; ( h >= 48 && h < 72)
 m[h_] := Exp[-(h/48)] + Exp[-((h - 24)/48)] + Exp[-((h - 48)/48)] + 
    Exp[-((h - 72)/48)] /; ( h >= 72 && h < 96)
 m[h_] := Exp[-(h/48)] + Exp[-((h - 24)/48)] + Exp[-((h - 48)/48)] + 
    Exp[-((h - 72)/48)] + Exp[-((h - 96)/48)] /; ( h >= 96 && h < 120)
 Plot[m[h], {h, 0, 120}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

This is exactly what I want. But now I want to optimize the code, so that I can also `Plot[]` for periods up to several weeks.

Question: How can I rewrite `m[h]` such that there will only be one line involved, i.e.  add the `Exp[-((h - 72)/48]` type of terms automatically?

Comment: You've seen `Piecewise[]`?

Comment: Yeah, but I am looking for a soln without the 'pieces'. I am hoping to get it something like m[h_] = Sum[m, {}]. I don't see it. My mma is getting rusty already. It's only 2 mo since I haven't used it.

Comment: For a half life of 24 hours you should be using `Exp[-Log[2] h/24]`

Comment: @Simon, so, `2^(-h/24)`? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose this function will suit your needs:

```
m[h_] := Sum[Exp[-((h - 24 k)/48)], {k, 0, Quotient[h, 24]}]

Plot[m[h], {h, 0, 300}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot of m[h]]

Comment: Oh yes, very compact indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different approach not using `Piecewise` that calculates the concentration and has the ability to account for *variable* doses at *variable* times both in the past and the future for drugs with any given half life.

It uses a list of `{dose, time}` pairs, time in hours. Negative times are doses received in the past.

```
concentration[t_, doses_List, halfLifeHours_] := 
 First@# If[t - Last@# <= 0, 0, 
      E^(-((Log[2] (t - Last@#))/halfLifeHours))] & /@ doses // Total
```

For a drug with unit dose, half life of 24 hours and a past and future doses regime ( 3 days in the past, 3 days into the future ) and a missed current dose.

```
doses = {{1, -72}, {1, -48}, {1, -24}, {1, 24}, {1, 48}, {1, 72}};
```

We can plot the resulting concentration:

```
Plot[concentration[t, doses, 24], {t, -144, 144}, PlotRange -> {{-144, 144}, {0, 3}}, 
     GridLines->Automatic]
```

[image: Concentration 1]

You can even see what would happen with irregularly spaced and incorrectly sized doses:

```
doses = {{1, -75}, {1, -43}, {.5, -25}, {1, 24}, {1, 48}, {1, 72}};
```

and thus:

```
Plot[concentration[t, doses, 24], {t, -144, 144}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-144, 144}, {0, 3}}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Concentration 2]

I imagine that a more accurate simulation would include the concentration increase from the point the drug was administered.

Comment: Very, very good, functionality rich answer but J.M.'s answer provided the most compact representation of the formula and that's what I originally asked for.

Comment: @ndroock1 no problem, glad you got some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Piecewise` and a little coding (where `Accumulate` will do the partial sums) :

```
m2[h_, nDays_] := Piecewise[Transpose[{Accumulate[
 Exp[-(h - #)/48] & /@ (24 Range[0, nDays - 1])],
     #[[1]] <= h < #[[2]] & /@ Partition[24 Range[0, nDays], 2, 1]}]]

m2[h,5]
```

[image]

```
Plot[m2[h, 5], {h, 0, 120}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. This already helps. But why the days apart?

Comment: Do you mean why the curve is not continuous ?

Comment: No the discontinuity is to be expected. I mean I would like a function from h which is Plot'able and can be used in other Mma calcs. Again: this already helps. Thanks.

Comment: In which way you cannot use it in other calculations ?

Comment: Well, it is not a function of h but from h and nDays. The concentration is only dependent on h. The daily intake is fact and fixed. Do you see the dilemma?

Comment: Maybe you can use a very large `nDays = 365` or so ?

Comment: I see it now, I can simply define m3[h_] := m2[h, 30] ( for example. ) That gives me what I want. Solved. - Also in this case the plot becomes "continuous" again.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Exp` is `Listable`, you can also define your function as

```
 mm[h_] := Total[Exp[-((h - 24 Range[0, Floor[h/24]])/48)]];
 Plot[mm[h], {h, 0, 300}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]